# Prometheus: How to run unit tests against PrometheusRule kubernetes manifests

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I wish to use `promtool` to run unit tests against alerts that I have setup e.g.

```
promtool test rules alert-test.yaml
```

Here's an example test file:

```
# alert-test.yaml
rule_files: 
- 'my-alert.yaml'
tests:
- name: 'Fire ManyRequests Alert'
  interval: 1s # every second
  input_series:
    - series: rate(http_requests_total[5m])
      values: '0+1x30' # starting at 0 requests per second increase to 30 requests per second
  alert_rule_test:
    - alertname: ManyRequests
      eval_time: 10s
      exp_alerts: # no alert
    - alertname: ManyRequests
      eval_time: 25s
      exp_alerts:
        - exp_labels:
            severity: p2
          exp_annotations:
            description: Request increase too high
```

Nothing new here. And this would be no problem if `my-alert.yaml` looked like this:

```
groups:
  - name: alert_group_name
    rules:
      - alert: ManyRequests
        expr: rate(http_requests_total[5m]) > 20
        for: 5s
        annotations:
          description: Request increase too high
        labels:
          severity: P2
```

but instead i have a Kubernetes manifest that is being deployed i.e.

```
my-alert.yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  labels:
    prometheus: prometheus-core-rules
    role: alert-rules
  name: tesla-maps-cert-alert-rules
spec:
  groups:
    - name: alert_group_name
      rules:
        - alert: ManyRequests
          expr: rate(http_requests_total[5m]) > 20
          for: 5s
          annotations:
            description: Request increase too high
          labels:
            severity: P2
```

so running `promtool test rules alert-test.yaml` throws this error:

```
Unit Testing:  alerts-test.yaml
  FAILED:
my-alert.yaml: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 1: field apiVersion not found in type rulefmt.RuleGroups
  line 2: field kind not found in type rulefmt.RuleGroups
  line 3: field metadata not found in type rulefmt.RuleGroups
  line 8: field spec not found in type rulefmt.RuleGroups
```

what can i do to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what can i do to get this working?

Just extract the relevant portion of the YAML manifest:

```
yq .spec my-alert.yaml > my-alert-for-testing.yaml
```

And modify your test file to reference the extracted file:

```
rules_files:
  - my-alert-for-testing.yaml
```

I'm using [this yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), but [the other one](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) should work as well.